# Django - Multiple user types (ability to switch between them)

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am doing some pre-planning on a project I am working on and my approach to it. A part of the app is the ability to have multiple user types. For example, a Company and a Contractor account type. Though it's important to note that a company can also be a contractor.

So the approach I was going to attempt to implement is similar to Upwork where there is one account, but they can switch between being a client and a freelancer if they wish. It would be ideal if the user didn't need to log out while switching between the two. I'm newer to the django framework and was hoping someone could shed light on the best possible approach to accomplish this while also taking into account scale-ability.

Comment: Concept you're refering to might be seen as `inheritance`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

In your case, as each account can either be "A" or "B" (both inheriting from User), you can use proxy models to split problematics to relevant classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), here is one way I would approach the problem (details follow the code):

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('COM', 'Company'),
        ('CON', 'Contractor'),
    ]

    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

    ...

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        # Try to retrieve the current object from the database.
        try:
            db_obj = User.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        except User.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            db_obj = None

        if db_obj
            # Check whether user_type is not to be updated (not in update_fields,
            # or hasn't changed its value).
            update_fields = kwargs.get('update_fields')
            if (update_fields and 'user_type' not in update_fields) or self.user_type == db_obj.user_type:
                super().save(*args, **kwargs)
                return

        # At this point, either the current object is being newly created,
        # or its user_type field is about change.

        if self.user_type == 'COM':
            ...  # Make changes when the user switches to Company mode
        elif self.user_type == 'CON':
            ...  # Make changes when the user switches to Contractor mode

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I add a field with `choices` set, and I override the `save` method to let me (re)configure the object's functionality based on whether it is being saved as a Company or a Contractor.

Benefits:

- Single user model
- No need for a user to log out
- Scalable (adding more user modes is only a matter of updating the choice set and perhaps adding some custom saving logic)